# Asymptote does not compile with miktex

Tags: graphics, pdf, miktex, texmaker, asymptote

So a few days ago I tried latex, I downloaded miktex and I also use texmaker as my text editor, I also downloaded several packages to work with and it went well. The problem arose when I tried to join Asymptote with latex.The first thing that I tried was to download asymptote and add it through a root directory, it didn't work. Here are some screenshots of what I tried to do.
[image]

and here are the content inside those that root directory.
[image]

But when i compiled it, the pdf would display correctly but without the diagrams (a.k.a the asymptote)
It would say something like this.

[image]

and if tried to compile it using asymptote it says "Error: could not start the command :"
I also tried downloading asymptote directly from miktex but it didn't work either.

Also I don't know if I have to do something here.
[image]

Note: this is how my latex file is displayed. Notice that in figure 1 a geometrical figure should be displayed but it is not, hopefully someone can help.
[image]

Comment: you don't have to install anything manually for asy in miktex, miktex provides all needed packages and binaries. But I don't think that it will work. A small test seems to indicate that asy requires a newer ghostscript, and miktex is still at 9.25.  You could try to install texlive beside your miktex.

Comment: I switched to Texlive and the same thing happened. Everything is displayed but not the geometrical diagrams.